# /bits/ 64 in device tree source - where this is defined?

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

I've seen this notation in some .dts files for arm64:

```
  &foo {
    addrs = /bits/ 64 <0x11223344556677aa>,
            /bits/ 64 <0x11223344556677bb>;
  };
```

Apparently, this means a 64-bit value.
But where this syntax is specified? It is not in the [latest 'official' spec](https://github.com/devicetree-org/devicetree-specification/releases/tag/v0.4-rc1).

Comment: It's implemented as a delimiter-starter string in **scripts/dtc/treesource.c** of kernel source.

Comment: Also look at descriptions for **of_property_read_u8_array()** and **of_property_read_u16_array()** in **include/linux/of.h**  But the 32- and 64-bit versions of those procedures don't bother to mention the use of that size specifier!?

Comment: The dtc in the kernel tree seems to come from "upstream" (see `scripts/dtc/update-dtc-source.sh`) so this /bits/ prefix looks like undocumented syntax extension, not specific to Linux  - if the target is aware of additional element sizes. @sawdust if you convert your comments to answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: The parser src for /bits/ 8|16|32|64 is in `scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.y` , arrayprefix: case (line 356)

Comment: Thanks but I'll pass on writing an answer, as my comments are just that, and I don't have anything to add.  I'm surprised that this isn't documented. Maybe you can collect all that you found, and answer your own post.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I'll answer my own question, with valuable help of @sawdust.

The `/bits/ 8|16|32|64` prefix is undocumented extension; it has been around for quite long, but not going to be legalized in the next devicetree.org spec (v. 0.4).

It allows to lay out array of values of the specified bitness (or a single value).

Prefix `/bits/ 32` gives exactly same result as no prefix.
There must be exactly one space after '/bits/' and between the number and '<'.

Linux has kernel API to read such arrays: `of_property_read_u64_array(), of_property_read_u32_array(), of_property_read_u16_array(), of_property_read_u8_array()`, defined in `include/linux/of.h`.
(For querying size of arrays defined with this prefix, use common APIs for 'standard' arrays).

It is handled by the `dtc` compiler in the Linux kernel tree (see `scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.y` , `arrayprefix:` case; near line 356).

Test and reference python code found on devicetree.org has no support of this prefix.